# How to switch C# REPL to x64?

Tags: c#-interactive

I am working with new C# REPL feature in VS 2015 Community Update 2. Is there an options to switch REPL to x64 (like there is an F# REPL) ?

Comment: Only academically, the REPL host process (InteractiveHost.exe) has the "Prefer 32-bit" option turned on.  Hacking it with CorFlags.exe could perhaps work but obviously voids the warranty.

Answer (score 2):

64-bit is not supported in C# interactive yet as the hosting process is 32-bit. It's in their pipeline though: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/7663